# What are the pros n cons of Multicore Processors and Multithreaded Processors (SMT)

Tags: cpu-architecture

With SMT parts of the one processor are shared between threads, while other parts are duplicated between them
On the other hand, multi-core processors embed two or more independent execution cores into a single processor package.

My question: What are the Pros n Cons of each architecture's in different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SMT parts of the one processor are shared between threads, while other parts are duplicated between them. One of the most important shared resources is the actual execution engine. This engine works on both threads at the same time by executing instructions for one thread on resources that the other thread is not using. When both threads are running, SMT Technology literally interleaves the instructions in the execution pipeline. Which instructions are inserted when depends wholly on what execution resources of the processor are available at execution time. Moreover, if one thread is tied up reading a large data file from disk or waiting for the user to type on the keyboard, the other thread takes over all the processor resources—without the operating system switching tasks—until the first thread is ready to resume processing. In this way, each thread receives the maximum available resources and the processor is kept as busy as possible.

SMT Technology achieves performance gains through latency hiding. Fundamentally, a single execution core is shared among multiple threads. Therefore, thread execution is not parallel. As a result, performance results vary based on application and hardware platform. 
SMT Advantages
•   general: better use of system resources 
•   parallelize tasks & enhanced performance on multi-processor machines
Disadvantages
•   synchronization of shared resources (objects, data)
•   "starvation": some threads may not be served with a bad design

On the other hand, multi-core processors embed two or more independent execution cores into a single processor package. By providing multiple execution cores, each sequence of instructions, or thread, has a hardware execution environment entirely to itself. This enables each thread run in a truly parallel manner. A

Note that a dual-core processor provides true parallel execution of each thread. It should be noted that SMT Technology does not attempt to deliver multi-core performance, which can theoretically be close to a 100-percent, or 2x improvement in performance for a dual-core system. SMT Technology is more of a facility in which the programmer may be able to use idle CPU resources in order to accomplish more work. When combined with multi-core technology, SMT Technology can provide powerful optimization opportunities, increasing system throughput substantially.

Comment: *Therefore, thread execution is not parallel* perhaps you're thinking of fine-grained multithreading?  In most true SMT implementations (like Intel Hyperthreading or AMD Zen), instructions from both/all logical cores can be dispatched to execution units in the same cycle.  e.g. each logical core could be running a dependency chain of 1-cycle latency `add` instructions, and both achieve full throughput (because they both bottleneck on latency).  But that's only possible if both cores can exec an `add` in the same cycle, otherwise they'd have half throughput.

Answer (score 3):

**There aren't really major cons, for high performance you want both.**

For high single-threaded performance *and* the option of trading some of that for more throughput, you want SMT.

But you can't make a single core extremely wide; it doesn't scale linearly, so adding more physical cores is a better way to spend transistors / power beyond a certain pipeline width.

**That's why all high-end modern CPUs *are* multi-core per die with each core supporting SMT.**  It allows you to trade per-thread performance for more total throughput, keeping more executions units busy on each core.

- Intel since Nehalem: multi-core with 2-way SMT
- Intel Xeon Phi (Knight's corner / landing / mill) *many* cores, each with 4-way SMT
- AMD Zen: multi-core with 2-way SMT
- IBM POWER8: multi-core with 8-way SMT

SPARC Niagara is a bit of an exception: it might not be considered truly SMT, but rather fine-grained multithreading, because each core can only issue one instruction / clock ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading)).

AMD experimented with CMT in Bulldozer: a cluster of weak integer cores sharing a SIMD / FPU.  This had good-ish throughput when there are enough threads to keep all the cores busy, but can't run fewer threads faster the way normal SMT can.